# How to replace \r\n by a paragraph with regular expression

Tags: java

I am getting a text in java as

> This request is to gather all the dependent eForms from funding opportunities and package them into a single container (zip) file.\r\n(space here)This file will be used for the import of eForms on target systems within the program office interface.

This text should be rendered in browser as:

> This request is to gather all the dependent eForms from funding opportunities and package them into a single container (zip) file.---next line----
>   ------paragraph separator----------- This file will be used for the import of eForms on target systems within the program office interface.

I have used below function to convert regular expression into html code:

```
notLogDetail.setBody(notLog.getBody().replaceAll("(\r\n|\n|\u0085|\u2028|\u2029)", "<br>"));
```

But as after `\r\n` there is paragraph separator which is in Java coming as blank space and therefore above function is not able to convert it and it renders in browser as below:

> This request is to gather all the dependent eForms from funding opportunities and package them into a single container (zip) file.
>   This file will be used for the import of eForms on target systems within the program office interface.

What should I use in order to display a paragraph in web browser?

Comment: Why don't you just use `<p>` instead of `<br>` if you intend a paragraph instead of a line break..?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the regular expression. The problem is that you want to use `<br>` where you shouldn't. You say yourself that you want to display paragraphs, so you should be using the `<p>` element (**p** as in _p_aragraph).

Instead of so replace the line breaks with `</p><p>`, add a `<p>` at the start and `</p>` at the end of the text and then use CSS to adjust the margin of the `<p>` element.

```
notLogDetail.setBody('<p>' + notLog.getBody().replaceAll("(\r\n|\n|\u0085|\u2028|\u2029)", "</p><p>") + '</p>' );
```

Comment: I cannot use <p> because the text that I am getting in java code is dynamic,I want to display a paragraph only if the text contains it.( a paragraph can be anywhere in the text).Secondly the text that I am getting from notLog.getBody() in java contains blank space for a paragraph separator.Therefore I am not able to replace it with any character.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand your comment. A text as you describe it, always has one paragaph (a paragraph is a "block of words", not the gap between them). Why can't you display just one paragraph?

Comment: The text that I gave was just an example.The text that I will get   may contain a paragraph or maynot.The notLog.getBody() will give me whole text and in between if there is a paragraph then I am suppose to replace it with some character that browser can understand and render a paragraph in web browser but not the whole text as paragraph.

Comment: What's wrong with displaying the whole text as one paragraph? With the correct stylesheet noone can tell a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try following replaceAll call:

```
notLog.getBody().replaceAll("(\r?\n|\u0085|\u2028|\u2029)\\s*", "<br>")
```